# Javascript/jQuery - On hover over a li element, change class of another li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having some trouble with the menu bar on this website: http://www.re-generation.ro/ro/campanii/minerit-aurifer .
Now, the second `li` element is active. What i want to do, is that on `hover` over any other `li` element in the menu, the `class` of the current active `li` element becomes blank and on on hover out, it becomes active again. If you visit the link you can easily understand what i what.

If you need any information pls ask.

thank you in advance!

My code:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('ul'); 
for (var i=0, len=lis.length; i<len; i++){ 
    lis[i].onmouseover = function(){ 
        var firstDiv = this.getElementsByTagName('li')[1]; 
        firstDiv.className = ''; 
        var ul = $(this).parent(document.this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1]); 
        ul.className = ''; 
    }; 
    lis[i].onmouseout = function(){ 
        var firstDiv = this.getElementsByTagName('li')[1]; 
        firstDiv.className = 'active'; 
    }; 
};
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers! That really helped!

Comment: My first tip would be either use jQuery or don't.

Comment: whoever answers this, refactor this mess into jquery

Comment: musicvicious: it makes more semantic sense to put hover events (and styling) on the A-tag, not the LI.

Comment: @mathletics i would really use whatever works best.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what should happen when I hover over the menu. Is it suppose to hide all the text and show the icon or hide other icon and text and show the current hovered icon?

Comment: @Huangism It should hide the icon and the text, and show the icon and the text of the hoverd element

Comment: Instead or `for` statement try with [Jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method

Comment: @Tom do not do that. There is no reason to use `each` in this case.

Comment: @Mathletics, you are right... I just read a piece of code (I'll be more careful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you probably want to do is assign two different states/classes: `active` and `current`. One tells you which one should be shown, and the other actually toggles the visibility.

```
$('#menu').on('mouseover', '> li', function(e) {
    # attach hover event to the menu, and check which LI you are hovering
    if (!$(this).hasClass('.current)')) {
        $('.current', '#menu').removeClass('active');
    }
}).on('mouseout', '> li', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('.current)')) {
        $('.current', '#menu').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Here you are selecting just the direct descendants and updating the class, provided it's not the currently active list item.

Comment: yea I just saw it, there is some other js adding hover class to show the content

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="current active">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#menu li').on('mouseover', function() {
    var li$ = $(this);
    li$.parent('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
    li$.addClass('active');
})
.on('mouseout', function() {
    var li$ = $(this);
    li$.removeClass('active');
    li$.parent('ul').find('li.current').addClass('active');
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/8zLGj/)

Comment: thank you Evgeniy for your answer. Unfortunately this is not working as i want. you can check it out and see the results.. thank you

Comment: I would imagine this would change the currently active tab on the page, it should default to the original tab on final mouseout

Comment: still doesn't work, but thank you for your answers! It really helped somehow :)  Mathletics code works like a charm.

Comment: This works great, I needed this for a responsive menu where there was an arrow and a hover menu item. I wanted both to have the same hover state color and this was a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery for this. Something like this:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
  $('li.active').removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
});

$('li').mouseleave(function(){
  $('li.normal').removeClass('normal').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: this would not do anything to the currently hovered li

Comment: I know, but the problem here was the active li showing while hovering another li.

Comment: This doesn't target _only_ the top level UL, so hovering the sub-elements of the active list will remove the `active` state.

Comment: @jlundela oh yea you are right there is some other js that's adding the class hover to show the items

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is a way to remember what the default state is.  Here is my answer, and a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/556g2/)**

HTML:

```
<ul class="menuWithDefault">
    <li><a href="/one.html">Link One</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/two.html">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/three.html">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/four.html">Link One</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".menuWithDefault").each(function() {
    var defaultItem = $(this).find(".active").first();

    $(this).find("li").hover(function() {
        defaultItem.toggleClass('active', false);
        $(this).toggleClass('active', true);
    }, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active', false);
        defaultItem.toggleClass('active', true);
    });
});​
​
```

Comment: I twiddled the JS some to allow for any number of menus, each with its own default state.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Mathletics answer dit id for me. But i really appreciate!

Answer (score -1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
        }); 
     });
```

```css
li.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.